# how can I transform a view from three.js camera and scene to a bcf cameraview

Tags: javascript, three.js, bcftools

I'm trying to create a bcf file out of the ifc.js viewer. The ifc.js viewer is using a three.js webglrenderer with a camera and scene.
Here is an example.

[image]
[image]
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/Camera
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene

How can I transform this view to a bcf view with CameraUpVector, CameraDirection and CameraViewPoint.
[image]

https://github.com/BuildingSMART/BCF-XML/tree/release_3_0/Documentation

Answer (score 0):

I found a transformation by my self.

```js
bcfCameraViewPointX = camera.position.x;
bcfCameraViewPointX = -camera.position.z;
bcfCameraViewPointX = camera.position.y;

//for the direction you have to calculate a vector out of the roation and the eulerOrder

let vector3 = new THREE.Vector3();
vector3.x = 0;
vector3.y = 0;
vector3.z = -1;

vector3.applyEuler(camera.rotation, camera.eulerOrder);

bcfCameraDirectionX = vector3.x;
bcfCameraDirectionX = -vector3.z;
bcfCameraDirectionX = vector3.y;

bcfCameraUpVectorX = camera.up.x;
bcfCameraUpVectorX = -camera.up.z;
bcfCameraUpVectorX = camera.up.y;

bcfFieldOfView = camera.fov;
```